# How do I grant read access to all home directories of members in a group?

Tags: linux, permissions, users, accounts

So I have 4 users on my redhat system.

*P- primary group

S- supplementary/secondary group*

UserA - **P**: Teacher    **S**:  USA

UserB - **P**: Teacher    **S**: School

UserX - **P**: Student **S**: School

UserY - **p**: Student **S**: School, USA

How do I allow everyone in School/USA secondary groups to have read access to all users' home directories in the group? e.g. UserX should be able to read User B & Y's home directories because they are in the group School. But UserX cannot read UserA's  home because UserX is not in USA.

UserY can read everyone's home.

Comment: haven't tried anything because I don't know how to even start!

Comment: This is a very obvious homework (or other coursework) question. The place where you got it from gave you a question without a place to start figuring it out? Hint, read up on file/directory ownership & permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest thing you can do is to add groups to each of your users, i.e. modifying your users! This task can be done by using `usermod` command. Read more [here](http://www.tecmint.com/usermod-command-examples/). Be aware that **-g** option is for user's new initial group (i.e. **Primary**) while **-G** option is a list of **supplementary** groups which the user can be also a member of. You can get more information by reading `usermod`'s manual page by running `man usermod`.

For permitting a member of a group to read everything under one's home directory, that home directory should have "read" permission bit on for groups, i.e. if your X home directory is `drwx------`, you should change it to be `drwxr-----` by using `chmod` command.
For using permission bits wisely, read about them [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).
In addition you can read about SUID, SGID, and Sticky bits [here](http://thegeekdiary.com/what-is-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bit/).
BTW, you should read [this](https://linuxfrombeginning.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/linux-command-9-chown-chgrp-chmod/) article to understand `chmod`, `chown`, and `chgrp` commands.

Let me know if you have any problems.

Good Luck

Comment: BTW, add -a option with the -G option if you want to append.